# Xamarin login(activation) error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I’m getting an error (activation) while logging into Xamarin studio on OSX.

Please find below the error. Let me know how to resolve the issue. Thanks.

There was an internal error in the activation system. Please contact Xamarin Support.

System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow (Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.LicenseSyncResult[] results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors) [0x00243] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2920/f73f730c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationService.cs:761 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService+c__Iterator3.MoveNext () [0x003f6] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2920/f73f730c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationService.cs:654 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep (Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationWorkflowStep step) [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2920/f73f730c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationDialog.cs:486 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog+c__AnonStorey4.<>m__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00051] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2920/f73f730c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationDialog.cs:584

Comment: It is very likely that you are running an Alpha or Beta channel build. Wait till Xamarin updates those channels.

Answer (score 1):

I just received the latest stable version(5.10.3.51) which resolved this issue.
See here --> https://releases.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running into the following error: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/188323/#Comment_188323 so it would be good to try those suggestions to see if that gets you up and running.