# Unhandled Activation Error

Tags: xamarin

I'm having an error when attempting to login in Xamarin IDE for Mac OS X:
[image]

```
System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow (Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.LicenseSyncResult[] results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors) [0x00264] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/ac9b7fcb/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationService.cs:762 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService+<GenerateFullWorkflowSequence>c__Iterator3.MoveNext () [0x00410] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/ac9b7fcb/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationService.cs:654 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep (Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationWorkflowStep step) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/ac9b7fcb/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationDialog.cs:463 
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog+<StartSpinnerTaskAndScheduleContinuation>c__AnonStorey4.<>m__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x0005b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2968/ac9b7fcb/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/Activation/ActivationDialog.cs:561
```

PS: Already have version Version 5.10.3 (build 26).

Comment: For reference, the question has also been asked 2 other times on Stack Overflow: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385508/unable-to-activate-xamarin-unhanded-error-visual-studio-2015-update-2) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36367833/2561894).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using an older version of Xamarin with one of the the new MSDN licenses.

The version that was updated to support the newer licenses is 5.10.3 build 51 - please check for updates via `Xamarin Studio -> Check for Updates`.

Answer (score 1):

Download the newer packages here :

http://download.xamarin.com/Installer/MonoForAndroid/jdk-7u71-macosx-x64.dmg

http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-darwin-x86_64.bin

http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Mac/XamarinStudio-5.10.3.51-0.dmg

http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Mac/xamarin.android-6.0.3-5.pkg

http://download.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-9.6.1.9.pkg

http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforMac/Mac/xamarin.mac-2.4.2.1.pkg