# Xamarin Activation fails in my Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I've applied the Update 2 to my Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition, 
I've bought it at no cost (thanks to the Microsoft/Xamarin acquisition/deal),
but when I've tried to activate it (yes, I was logged out of Xamarin account inside the VS IDE) this error appears...

```
System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.GetErrorWorkflow(LicenseSyncResult[] results, Boolean ignoreSyncErrors)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationService.<GenerateFullWorkflowSequence>d__88.MoveNext()
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.DisplayWorkflowStep(ActivationWorkflowStep step)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Activation.ActivationDialog.<>c__DisplayClass13.<StartSpinnerTaskAndScheduleContinuation>b__12(Task t)
```

Please help, this update also affected my IIS Express installation. And now Xamarin... Thanks in advance.-

Comment: For reference, the question has also been asked 3 other times on Stack Overflow: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36385508/2561894), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36367833/2561894), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36423728/2561894).

Comment: Actually, it might be best to mark this as a duplicate of  [Unable to activate Xamarin Unhanded ERROR - Visual Studio 2015 update 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36385508/2561894) to keep reports of this error in Visual Studio separate from the reports in Xamarin Studio. Apologies for the slightly imprecise duplication flag in my first comment.

Comment: I will now test the given options and provide feedback. 
Thanks a lot for your help. 

I've had some troubles finding a solution for this question, don't know why. But if marking this as a duplicate is going to help other people, then please proceed; in order to keep everything simple and easy to find.

I have a strong hunch that there's going to be even more duplicated questions regarding this (important) Update 2, and this topic (Visual Studio and Xamarin). Thanks again.-

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues,

1. goto Tool Menu
2. then Options
3. In the window that pops up , Under the Xamarin, choose other
4. click on Check Update button.

   You should find an update pending ( 4.0.3.214), download that and try again. It should work.
   Good luck :)

Comment: I'm going to try this solution right away, thank you Joseph!

Comment: update: After I've posted the question I decided to reinstall the whole standalone Xamarin product. And the installer informed me that updates on several components were needed. 

Then, when everything was re-installed and updated I've tried to log into my Xamarin account from within Visual Studio, and I was able to do it instantly. It seems you were correct.

Comment: Microsoft has changed the licensing of Xamarin. I guess that might have caused it.